# Insert or update data to the database in phoenix elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have got this in my database:

```
[
  %Element{id: 1, posx: 1, posy: 2, count1: 100, count2: 500, timestamps...},
  %Element{id: 2, posx: 2, posy: 2, count1: 150, count2: 450, timestamps...},
  %Element{id: 3, posx: 3, posy: 2, count1: 50, count2: 300, timestamps...}
]
```

Now when I add new data

```
  Repo.insert{posx: 3, posy: 2, count1: 25 count2: 125}
```

I want to update the existing entry where posx AND posy are the same and add the two new count values.
So my database should look like this:

```
[
  %Element{id: 1, posx: 1, posy: 2, count1: 100, count2: 500, timestamps...},
  %Element{id: 2, posx: 2, posy: 2, count1: 150, count2: 450, timestamps...},
  %Element{id: 3, posx: 3, posy: 2, count1: 75, count2: 425, timestamps...}
]
```

If an entry entry where posx AND posy are the same doesnt exist I just want to insert a new entry to the database.

so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select and then either update or insert.

```rb
q = from(Element, where: [posx: 3, posy: 2])
case Repo.one(q) do
  nil -> 
    Repo.insert(...)
  %Element{count1: count1} = e -> 
    e = Ecto.Changeset.change(e, count1: count1 + 25)
    Repo.update(e)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be Repo.insert(struct_or_changeset, opts) as explained in the documentation https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert/2

So, try this instead

```
Repo.insert(%Element{id: 3, posx: 3, posy: 2, count1: 25 count2: 125})
```

If you want to check whether the data exists and want to update if so, use on_conflict option.

Probably like this.

```
# In Postgres (it requires the conflict target for updates):
on_conflict = [set: [body: "updated"]]
{:ok, updated} = Repo.insert(%Element{id: 3, posx: 3, posy: 2, count1: 25 count2: 125}, on_conflict: on_conflict, conflict_target: :id)

# In MySQL (conflict target is not supported):
on_conflict = [set: [title: "updated"]]
{:ok, updated} = Repo.insert(%Element{posx: 3, posy: 2, count1: 25 count2: 125}, on_conflict: on_conflict)
```

Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: This by no means answers “I want to update the existing entry where posx AND posy are the same and add the two new count values..”